# ui-router parent state optional parameter

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to manage CRUD for lists and list elements.

I want to have **one state, one template and one controller** per element for each case(create/edit).

I create the state:

```
state('list', {
                parent: 'root',
                url: '/list?list_id',
                views: {
                    'content@root': {
                        templateUrl: 'list.tmpl.html',
                        controller: 'ListController',
                        controllerAs: 'vm',
                    }
                }
            })
```

Which is perfect, in the controller i can check for a list_id and toggle betweend create/edit.

The problem occurs when the state above becomes a parent.
When the child is introduced:

```
state('list-element', {
                parent: 'list',
                url: '/element?list_id&element_id',
                views: {
                    'content@root': {
                        templateUrl: 'element.tmpl.html',
                        controller: 'ElementController',
                        controllerAs: 'vm',
                    }
                }
            })
```

I can no longer have the uncertainty i need.

To put it more simple, i want the url structure to look like this:

- /list?list_id - if list_id toggle edit
- /list/element?list_id&element_id - if element_id toggle edit

**Note that when the list element is created, the parent state does not have a parameter.**

Now, i can work around this by creating two states for the list:

1. /list  (parent) *create*
2. ?list_id (child for 1) *edit*
3. /element?list_id&element_id (child for 1) *create or edit*

but this would break the "**one state, one template and one controller**" that i want.

Anyway that i can achieve to do it *the way i want*?

Answer (score 0):

I know you're looking for a specific implementation, but I think part of the reason you're hitting trouble is because that approach may not be the best for what you're trying to do, since it seems like you're confusing the role of a route versus a DOM element.

Components (and directives) are designed to help you bundle together controllers and templates explicitly for elements on the page. Routing is just what gets you there, and tells you which ones to load. Here's how you might handle this using a more conventional approach:

```
stateHelperProvider.state({
  name: 'list', 
  url: '/list'
  // This is possible with https://github.com/marklagendijk/ui-router.stateHelper
  children: {
    name: 'element',
    // Example: /list/123
    url: '/{list_id:int}?element_id',
    resolve: {
      item: ['$stateParams', 'FooService', ($stateParams, FooService) => {
        // Get whatever info you need, based on the ID.
        return FooService.getItem($stateParams.list_id);
      }
    },
    views: {
      'content@root': {
        // This will use the resolved `item` and pass it into the component.
        template: '<list-element item="$resolve.item"></list-element>'
      }
    }
  }
});

// The component
(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('yourModule')
    .component('listElement', {
      templateUrl: 'element.tmpl.html',
      bindings: {
        item: '<'
      }
    });
})();

// Sample component template
<h2 ng-bind="$ctrl.item.name"></h2>
<div ng-bind="$ctrl.item.description"></div>
```

For a different route, you may want to check out [nested named views in UI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views). This will allow you to specify a different controller, template, and state each. Gist:

```
<!-- Parent template -->
<div ui-view="editContents"></div>
<div ui-view="previewContents"></div>
```

Comment: I have solved the problem in another way: I made the '/list' state as a root with the default substate to '?list_id'. From there, I implemented the '?list_id' and '/element?list_id&element_id' as childs to '/list' and that worked just fine for me. For me, It seems that you over-complicate stuff. Thank you for your time!